# Set Google Plus profile URL to resolve to about page

Tags: google-plus

The standard Google Plus URL (for example: https://plus.google.com/109229333624640995186 ) resolves to the posts page (i.e. https://plus.google.com/109229333624640995186/posts ) by default. Is there a way to set this URL to resolve to the about page (i.e. https://plus.google.com/109229333624640995186/about ) instead?

Answer (score 1):

No. No such feature is available yet. And if you follow the other social networks out there, they also follow the same trend. The about page is usually never the landing page. It's a way of promoting the content of the web service and encouraging communication.

Usually professional sites like LinkedIn follow that trend, as in professional field the about page is more important than the content by that user. It is more of a resume and less of a social profile. But for a simple social network, the activity feed gets more priority.